PR notification to teams channel via Azure devops throwing 400 bad request
Created following:

"Incoming webhook" connector on teams channel

"Service hook" on azure devops to send out the notification to teams channel when a PR is raised.


After 2nd step, when "Test" is performed, receiving 400 bad request.

Also, Cannot use "Azure devops" connector on teams due to organisational restrictions.

Hi @Sanket Singh, the Incoming Webhooks connector on Teams channel cannot be used directly in the "Service hook" on azure devops. It needs a JSON payload with a message in card format. Please check the details in my answer and let me know if you have more questions.

In the Microsoft Teams Incoming Webhooks document, it mentions that

The webhooks provide a unique URL to send a JSON payload with a message in card format. Cards are user interface containers that include content and actions related to a single article.

In this case, the body you send to the URL in Azure DevOps web hooks is not in a card format so that it returns 400.
The card format body sample:
{
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "test text"
                    }
                ],
                "$schema": "http: //adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "version": "1.0"
            }
        }
    ]
}

Workaround
In the workaround, I use the Generic webhook based triggers for YAML pipelines. With this, we can subscribe to a webhook and trigger a pipeline. In the pipeline, we can consume the payload data in the form of variables and use a PowerShell task to send POST command to the URL you get from "Incoming webhook" connector on Teams channel.
Detailed steps:

Create an Incoming Webhooks service connection


Create a Service hook web hook with Pull request created event. The Request Url is "https://dev.azure.com/<ADO Organization>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHook Name>?api-version=6.0-preview". The WebHook Name is the one you set in the service connection.


Create a pipeline with the resource type webhooks. The pipeline will be triggered when the Pull request created webhook event is received by the Incoming Webhook service connection and you can consume the payload data in the form of variables in your jobs.


Sample Yaml:
trigger: none
resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: MyWebhookTrigger         ### Webhook name
      connection: MyWebhookConnection    ### Incoming webhook service connection name

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    ### JSON payload data is available in the form of ${{ parameters.<WebhookAlias>.<JSONPath>}}
    script: |
      Write-Host "Message.text: ${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.message.text}}"
      
      Write-Host "Message.markdown: ${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.message.markdown}}"
      
      $URL= ""   ### The URL you get from "Incoming webhook" connector on Teams channel.
      
      $body = @"
      {
          "type": "message",
          "attachments": [
              {
                  "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                  "content": {
                      "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                      "body": [
                          {
                              "type": "TextBlock",
                              "text": "${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.message.markdown}}"
                          }
                      ],
                      "$schema": "http: //adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                      "version": "1.0"
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
      "@
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Method 'POST' -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'

Test result:

